# Unable to execute git command in Perl

Tags: perl, git

Hi! I have no problem running

> git log --grep="cherry picked" --all > cherrypicklog.txt

from the command line.  However it failed to execute in Perl.

```
my $result = `git log --grep="cherry picked from commit" --all > cherrypicklog.txt`;
```

`git` is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

What am I missing?  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know much perl at all but I think this is just a general case of git not being in the `PATH` environment from your perl script. Try using an absolute path:

```
my $result = `/path/to/bin/git log --grep="cherry picked from commit" --all > cherrypicklog.txt`;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I found the problem is due to the fact that I run it in Eclipse.  If I ran it from the shell then it worked fine.

Comment: Another question; is there some setting in Eclipse IDE that doesn't get set properly?  Because even if I specified the full path, it still failed.  For example;  my $result = `/usr/bin/git log --grep="cherry picked from commit" --all > cherrypicklog.txt`  ===> The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: Found it.  All I have to do was to modify "Run Configuration" in Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Cool. Make sure to check the answer if it solved your problem. Glad you found out which environment needed fixing.